# Pivot a column to multiple columns based on regex pattern

Tags: python, pandas

There are 33 columns in my dataframe -

`Description_1_1, Description_2_1, Description_3_1,Description_1_2, Description_2_2, Description_3_2` etc.

I need to make 11 columns based out a pattern -
First word should be description and it should end with a number

```
Description_1
Description_2
Description_3
Description_4
Description_5
Description_6
Description_7
Description_8
Description_91
Description_92
Description_93
```

First I am thinking to unpivot these 33 columns in a single column Description using

`pandas.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Description'], i=['uuid'], j='dropme', suffix='_[^_]+_[^_]+$')).reset_index()`

But I am not able to get what should be the logic to create 11 columns out of this single column `Description` based on the integer after last underscore.

Expected output

```
Description_1 , Description_2
Description_1_1, Description_1_2
Description_2_1, Description_2_2
Description_3_1, Description_3_2
```

Comment: you should provide a better example (maybe avoiding the repeated use of the same digits before and after the `_` to be non ambiguous. `Description_A_1` might be better)

Answer (score 0):

What you want exactly is unclear (please provide a clear input), but here is a suggestion:

```
(pd.DataFrame(df.columns.str.split(r'_(?=\d+$)', expand=True).tolist())
   .assign(values=df.columns)
   .pivot(index=0, columns=1, values='values')
   .reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
                 1                2
0  Description_1_1  Description_1_2
1  Description_2_1  Description_2_2
2  Description_3_1  Description_3_2
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('x', index=[0, 1],
                  columns=['Description_1_1', 'Description_2_1',
                           'Description_3_1', 'Description_1_2',
                           'Description_2_2', 'Description_3_2'],)
```